# Hebrew text showing rectangle in iOS on UIlabel?

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, hebrew, rectangles

I have hebrew text and when I am showing on `UILabel` it showing some rectangle. please help.

Actual Text :-

> בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה יְיָ, אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ מֶֽלֶךְ הָעוֹלָם, בּוֹרֵא פְּרִי הָעֵץ

out put :-

[image]

UPDATE :- I have created the `UILabel` Manually using storyboard xib and set font name and rectangles gone but when i using on programatically created `UILabel` it is not working.I double checked Font Name is fine .Any idea?

Font is :- Arial Hebrew(family name)
           ArialHebrew-Bold (font name)
           ArialHebrew (font name)

Comment: Do you mean each hebrew character is being replaced by a square, or is there a single rectangle covering the whole text?

Comment: The font you are using may not have glyphs for each hebrew character. Try a different font.

Comment: only few are rectangle ,Please vote up the question so that I would be able to upload the screen shot that will give you more clear picture.

Comment: like from right  first two are converting in Rectangle.

Comment: iOS 6 have Arial Hebrew and bold of that that's all

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5484

Comment: I have added the image , please tell me it is right or wrong?

Comment: I am using [subTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Hebrew" size:12]];if any thing wrong in it please tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check by mistake if you would be setting the system font size or font name again then it's won't work.Do it only once.