# CSV to NSString to NSData with Hebrew text issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, export-to-csv

I'm creating a `CSV` file from CoreData using `CHCSVWriter`, so far so good and the file is creating perfectly. My problem is when i'm trying to send the `CSV` file that i've created i'm running in some issues, I open the `CSV` file with Excel and instead of Hebrew text I see gibberish.

While using `NSLog` to print the result of the `CSV` string, I see the Hebrew just fine. Even after converting it from `NSString` to `NSData` and back again.

This is what I get:
`×™×•×¡×™ ×¦×¤×¨`

This is my code:

```
- (void)createCSV
{
    CHCSVWriter *writer = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initForWritingToCSVFile:[self csvFilePath]];
    for (EWDBUsers *user in self.users)
    {
        [writer writeField:user.name];
        [writer writeField:user.company];
        [writer writeField:user.email];
        [writer writeField:user.telephone];
        [writer finishLine];
    }

    [writer closeStream];
}

- (NSString*)csvFilePath
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = @"users.csv";
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}

- (void)showMailComposerController
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [controller setSubject:@"Users List"];
        [controller setMessageBody:@"Attachment." isHTML:NO];

        NSError *error;
        NSString *csvFileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[self csvFilePath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", csvFileString);
        NSData *csv = [csvFileString dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        [controller addAttachmentData:csv mimeType:@"text/cvs" fileName:@"users.csv"];

        if (controller) {
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did any body face issue like this  "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955858/hebrew-text-showing-rectangle-in-ios-on-uilabel", please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing gibberish because you're converting Unicode to ASCII. `[csvFileString dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]` should be `[csvFileString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Also, `mimeType:@"text/cvs"` should be `mimeType:@"text/csv"`.

**EDIT:** The issue seems to be Excel. Opening the received CSV file in TextEdit displays just fine.

[image] [image]

Comment: Did also with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but the same issue.

Comment: I guess that in Windows the CSV file will work good, maybe it's just a problem with the Excel for Mac. Great answer man, working great with TextEdit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is adding BOM chars at start to solve a bug in Excel when try to open CSV files and save the UTF-8 Encoding.

```
cvsStringFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"\357\273\277%@", cvsStringFile];

NSData *myXLSData = [cvsStringFile dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[picker addAttachmentData:myXLSData mimeType:@"text/csv;charset=utf-8" fileName:@"Report.csv"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, there is an encoding issue. You are sending generated file with an invalid MIME type: `text/cvs`.

I would use text/plain with an explicit charset parameter, e.g.

`text/plain; charset=utf-8`

and explicitly encode the csv string into an `NSData` using that encoding (e.g. `NSUTF8StringEncoding`).

#### Edit:

Actually, there is a MIME type `text/csv`

So, you may also use:  `text/csv; charset=utf-8`

Comment: You need to be more specific. Can you read the received file with a text editor? Is is proper UTF-8? Do source file and destination file compare equal? Is there any error message?