# How can create a UIButton with Hebrew language text?

Tags: ios, uibutton, right-to-left

Problem:
Text (Hebrew language) which I set in button shows conversely.

For example:

```
      NSString *title = @"עמוד הבית"; //This is right-to-left
      UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

so:
In my simulator i see:

```
//This is left-to-right
```

[image: This is left-to-right]

How can it fix?

**How can I show text correctly?**

**App supported iOS 6 and iOS 7**

Comment: What does it mean? Not that that's relevant. Looks like the same thing you typed in just backwards.

Comment: It's being reversed because Hebrew is a right-to-left language. You should be using localized .strings files.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that right-to-left languages do not "mirror" each character (as shown in the Simulator output). - Are you sure that the transformation matrix is not modified somewhere? Do Latin characters display correctly?

Comment: What's your Xcode version? I tried your code for a button in my project, and it works fine with a system button, but with a custom type, it just doesn't display the text! However I am also an `RTL` developer and I understand how Apple sucks at supporting it. But with the recent versions of SDK it works fine.
@MartinR That can happen if the environment really sucks at supporting `RTL`.

Comment: Also, does this happen with `UITextLabel`s or `UITextView`s, too?

Comment: I solve this problem.

Comment: @Vit: Please post your solution (as an answer).

Comment: Sorry it my big bug; I put this button in Scroller but before I have done _scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);

Comment: Did you face this issue?please help "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955858/hebrew-text-showing-rectangle-in-ios-on-uilabel"

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me when using an UIButton was this:

```
if ([UIView userInterfaceLayoutDirectionForSemanticContentAttribute:button.semanticContentAttribute] == UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirectionRightToLeft)
{
    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
}
```

Links worth reading:

[Supporting Right-to-Left Languages (Apple Reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH17-SW1)

[AutoLayout + RTL + UILabel text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744447/autolayout-rtl-uilabel-text-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

if you use "#x200F" that will solve your problem,add this as appended string.There is one issue is after adding it all come with and that's weird,if you know the answer.Please, share

Comment: That's the right-to-left mark (RLM):  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark